# NSAppleEventDescriptor huge memory leak, obj-c

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

```
    NSDictionary *error = nil;

//AppleScript to get all running windows
NSAppleScript *appleScriptFindWindows = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:
                         @"tell application \"System Events\" to get the title of every window of process \"TestWindow\" whose name contains \"Black\" end tell"];


while (true) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        //Execute and get the result of the OSAScript
        NSAppleEventDescriptor *result = [appleScriptFindWindows executeAndReturnError:&error];

        //Convert the result to a string
        NSString *windowNames = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", result];

        error = nil;

        sleep(0.25);
    }

}
```

I know I am not currently doing anything with result but I will do once I have the issue fixed.

I will be monitoring various windows/files using applescript on a continuous loop, however I have noticed that when I run this code my memory usage skyrockets at 12mb/s and energy impact is high. I cannot release or de-alloc AppleEventDescriptor because of arc.

Is there a way to release the event descriptor or perhaps I am missing something in the applescript itself to correctly exit after execution?

I am a bit lost on this one and being new to obj-c I am wondering if there is a better way to execute applescript within obj-c if that is the issue.

Comment: You must not poll in a closed loop, and you must not say `sleep`. Therefore this can't be real code. Without real code, this isn't a real problem.

Comment: Hmm, I want to monitor the title of a window as it changes dynamically and I need to check it every 250ms or so, I thought the sleep would help reduce cpu usage until I need to break (break would only come on a certain window title), any suggestions on how I can structure this correctly?

Comment: The way to do something at intervals is to use an NSTimer.